# How to divide NSObject by a number in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I have this code:

```
NSObject *distanceInMeters;
distanceInMeters = [[[[[[googleMapsApiResult objectForKey:@"routes"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"legs"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"distance"] valueForKey:@"value"];
NSLog(@"%@", distanceInMeters); // this outputs 7578
NSDecimalNumber *roundTripInKilometers;
roundTripInKilometers = distanceInMeters / 500; // It says "Invalid operands to binary expression ('NSObject *' and 'int')
```

I expect to get 15.156 but it cannot divide object value with an integer. What should I do to get 15.156?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't divide number from NSObject, To do the same, You have to fetch the number from it and use it anywhere

```
 NSNumber *distanceInMeters;
distanceInMeters = [[[[[[googleMapsApiResult objectForKey:@"routes"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"legs"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"distance"] valueForKey:@"value"];
NSLog(@"%@", distanceInMeters); // this outputs 7578

NSDecimalNumber *roundTripInKilometers = (NSDecimalNumber *)[NSDecimalNumber numberWithDouble:[distanceInMeters doubleValue] / 500.0];
```

Comment: Why do you cast a `NSDecimalNumber` to a `NSDecimalNumber`?

Comment: Sorry I didn’t get you

Comment: `[NSDecimalNumber numberWithDouble:…` returns a `NSDecimalNumber`, why do you cast this `NSDecimalNumber` to `NSDecimalNumber`?

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems in your code. First, you need to convert the value you get from the API into an double. An easy way to do that would be to first convert it to an instance of `NSString`. Then get an double from the string with the method `doubleValue`.

Next divide that value by 500:

```
double roundTripInKilometersDouble = distanceInMeters / 500.0;
```

Then put that result into an `NSDecimalNumber`:

```
NSDecimalNumber *roundTripInKilometers = [NSDecimalNumber numberWithDouble: roundTripInKilometersDouble];
```

(Haven't tested this code.)

Comment: Is `roundTripInKilometersInt` an integer? It won't produce 15.156, but 15.

Comment: roundTripInKilometers**Int** is a double?